# DRY way to switch order of execution

Tags: vba, excel

In the function bellow (which I haven't tested yet), I am need to move valuees in array, and then resize array accordingly, problem is that depending on if we are moving values up in the index, or down I need to either resize the array first or move the values. As you can see I have an `If` statement and wihtin it there is cove for move and resize, but both scenarios have same come( only order of the lines was switched), is there a DRYer way to write that?

```
Private Function Update_Index(index As Interger, move As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim last As Integer
    last = UBound(Var_array, 2)
    If move < 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve Var_array(2, last + move)
        For i = index - 1 To last
            Var_array(i, 1) = Var_array(i + move, 1)
            Var_array(i, 2) = Var_array(i + move, 2)
        Next i
    Else
        For i = index - 1 To last
            Var_array(i, 1) = Var_array(i + move, 1)
            Var_array(i, 2) = Var_array(i + move, 2)
        Next i
        ReDim Preserve Var_array(2, last + move)
    End If
End Function
```

NOTE: In this case repetition seems harmless but I'm anitcipating bigger chunks of code with such needs.

Comment: Where is this defined? `Var_array()`

Comment: You might want to create an account on [codereview.se], if you want your working code to be peer reviewed - Stack Overflow is typically for *broken* code, CR makes your code *better* :)

Comment: If you take @retailcoder's advice, please stop by [CR's help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question.

Comment: @ckuhn203 I like retailcoder's advice and I think I'll just that thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a subroutine to pass the array to by reference.

```
Private Sub Update(ByRef array as variant, ByVal index as long, ByVal move as long)
    For i = index - 1 To ubound(array)
        Var_array(i, 1) = Var_array(i + move, 1)
        Var_array(i, 2) = Var_array(i + move, 2)
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Update_Index(index As Interger, move As Integer) As Boolean
    If move < 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve Var_array(2, last + move)

        Update Var_array, index, move
    Else

        Update Var_array, index, move

        ReDim Preserve Var_array(2, last + move)
    End If
End Function
```

You could probably extract another method, but I'm unsure of why you `ReDim` before and after depending on the move size.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function Update_Index(index As Integer, move As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim last As Integer
    last = UBound(Var_array, 2)
    If move < 0 Then ReDim Preserve Var_array(2, last + move)
    For i = index - 1 To last
        Var_array(i, 1) = Var_array(i + move, 1)
        Var_array(i, 2) = Var_array(i + move, 2)
    Next i
    If move > 0 Then ReDim Preserve Var_array(2, last + move)
End Function
```